# Downloading from a file sharing website it's safe?

Tags: anonymity

i'm new to Tor, i read the infos about encription between me and the entry point of network, the encryption inside the network and the unsafe connetion out of network to the end point.
My question is, if i download a file from the end point, a file web hoster or even a simple website, the download comes to me through the tor network and then log on the remote server will show the ip of tor network or the download will be direct to me and then the log will show them my ip?

I think it's the first case, but better to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading is (or at least it should be) safe, so it is the first case. BUT you should be careful when opening downloaded files, they can de-anonimize you (especially pdf & .txt files). The best way to be sure would be to disconnect before opening a file.

Comment: If a plaintext file can reveal your identity you have more serious issues... That's one poor text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Tor will anonymize your download. The IP-address which is known by the Server you're downloading from is the Exit-Point's address.

But be careful: Beside a lot of typical pitfalls (mentioned above), which could de-anonimize you, using a typical Browser for downloading could expose you by Browser-Fingerprinting . Using the Tor-Browser, Tor-Button or, as a linux user, tools like wget can defend your anonymity. More self-defence in reference to Browser-Fingerprinting is covered [here](https://panopticlick.eff.org/self-defense.php).